# Get latitude and longitude with Geocoder

Tags: android, google-maps, geocoding, google-maps-api-2

may i know how can i make the search result that show longitude and latitude of the place i search instead of showing the place name i search. btw, this code i copied from johnkil / GeocoderExample. and may i know what is LOG_TAG? thanks for ur reply :D

```
package com.ccsy.mtravel;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        private static final String LOG_TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

        private ListView list;
        private EditText edit;
        private Button search_Btn;

        private AddressArrayAdapter adapter;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onCreate() called");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        edit = (EditText) findViewById(android.R.id.edit);
        search_Btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.search_btn);

        adapter = new AddressArrayAdapter(this);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        search_Btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                new SearchTask().execute(new String[] {edit.getText().toString()});
                        }
                });

        if (!Geocoder.isPresent()) {
                search_Btn.setEnabled(false);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Geocoder methods getFromLocation and getFromLocationName are not implemented", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private class SearchTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Address>> {

                @Override
                protected List<Address> doInBackground(String... params) {
                        String locationName = params[0];
                        Log.v(LOG_TAG, String.format("search() called: locationName=[%s]", locationName));
                        List<Address> addresses = null;
                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
                    try {
                            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationName, 5);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                Log.w(LOG_TAG, e);
                        }
                        return addresses;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(List<Address> result) {
                        if (result != null && !result.isEmpty()) {
                                adapter.setData(result);
                        }
                }

    }

    private class AddressArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Address> {

            private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

            public AddressArrayAdapter(Context context) {
            super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2);
            mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

            public void setData(List<Address> data) {
            clear();
            if (data != null) {
                for (Address address : data) {
                    add(address);
                }
            }
        }

            private class ViewHolder {
                        TextView text1;
                TextView text2;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    final ViewHolder holder;
                    View view = convertView;
                if (view == null) {
                    view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, parent, false);
                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    holder.text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                    holder.text2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
                    view.setTag(holder);
                } else {
                        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
                }
                Address address = getItem(position);
                holder.text1.setText(address.getAddressLine(0));
                    holder.text2.setText(address.getAddressLine(1));
                return view;
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: log tag is whatever you want to be that indicates the log event, most people use the tag as the class name. did you try running the code? what happens that you dont understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
holder.text1.setText(address.getAddressLine(0));
holder.text2.setText(address.getAddressLine(1));
```

To this:

```
holder.text1.setText(address.getLatitude());
holder.text2.setText(address.getLongitude());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is returning the physical address here:
 addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName...

That resturns a List of Address Objects, with 5 values as specified.

To return the lat long you need to use the methods in the Address object to get them:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html

So get the first address in the addresses list, then getLatitude & getLongitude:

addresses.get(0).getLatitude();
addresses.get(0).getLongitude();

Hope that helps.